# Android ActionBarShelock onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: android, menu, actionbarsherlock, menuitem

I using action bar by sherlock. I'm trying to implement it into my app. But seems like I am missing something to make it to work. Please check on my codes. My app doesnt do anything when i tap on the action buttons. Below are my codes and my xml.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);


         menu.add("Share")
         .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

         menu.add("Save")
         .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

         menu.add("Set")
         .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.share:
        new share(this).execute(image_url);
        return true;
    case R.id.save:
        new save(this).execute(image_url);
        return true;
    case R.id.set:
        new set(this).execute(image_url);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

My menu xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <item android:id="@+id/share"
       android:title="@string/share"/>

 <item
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:title="@string/save"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/set"
        android:title="@string/set"/>


</menu>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set `OnMenuItemClickListener` on your menu items like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    menu.add("Share")
        .setOnMenuItemClickListener(this.mShareButtonClickListener)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

    // Other items...

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Then you create your OnMenuItemClickListener:

```
OnMenuItemClickListener mShareButtonClickListener = new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {  

         // Example of action following your code
         new share(YouActivity.this).execute(YouActivity.this.image_url);
         return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: I got this error "Cannot invoke setOnMenuItemClickListener(MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener) on the primitive type void"

Comment: excuse me, my mistake, I edited. You must set the listener before setting ShowAsAction(..) because it returns void

Comment: One more question. So do i need to create an extra OnMenuItemClickListener for each button i want to put in?

Comment: Not mandatory, you can use the same OnMenuItemClickListener for multiple menu items if you prefer and recognize them using the item.getItemId() method, inside the onMenuItemClick(MenuItem).

Answer (score 1):

You are inflating menu from menu's xml and also add in onCreateOptionsMenu, either of this should be done not both

```
 menu.add(Menu.NONE, PREF_MENU_ITEM, Menu.NONE, R.string.channel_preferences_menu_label).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, FEEDBACK_MENU_ITEM, Menu.NONE, R.string.feedback_from_menu_label).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, ABOUT_MENU_ITEM, Menu.NONE, R.string.about_app_menu_label).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);
        // commenting out this line because this func dosent have any use case
        // for APP version 3.0.0
//      menu.add(Menu.NONE, SOCIAL_MENU_ITEM, Menu.NONE, R.string.social_app_menu_label).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, FAQ_MENU_ITEM, Menu.NONE, R.string.faq_app_menu_label).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, DIAGNOSIS_MENU_ITEM, Menu.NONE, R.string.diagnosis_app_menu_label).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, MY_ACCOUNT_MENU_ITEM, Menu.NONE, R.string.account_app_menu_label).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);
```